# Understanding ReduxForm connect function syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

## What I'm used to:

I'm used to seeing something like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);
```

with `mapDispatchToProps` looking like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({selectBook: selectBook}, dispatch);
}
```

## What I've come across (in ReduxForm):

```
export default reduxForm({ 
  validate,
  form: 'PostsNewForm'
})(
  connect(null, {createPost})(PostsNew)
);
```

I find *this part* especially puzzling: `connect(null, {createPost})(PostsNew)`.

How exactly is this line of code different to the code above? And why don't we need mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: The duplicate question may not address the same thing as yours, but the answer to it explains both the things

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapStateToProps` if you want. it is not required by `react-redux` though.

Example taken from the [DOCS](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/faq/howtoconnect.md/):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Example extends Component {
    // ...
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // ...
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)  => ({
    // ...
});

Example = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Example);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'example' // a unique name for this form
})(Example);
```

Answer (score 0):

connect's `mapDispatchToProps` allows a shorthand form of an object literal, that is, if the function you are mapping to (the end result passed to your component) has the same signature as the action creator that will be dispatched, it's kind of noisy to have to do all that `bindActionCreator` stuff. Passing an object literal as the `mapDispatchToProps` argument tells react-redux to do this for you.

So, your first example can be rewritten as

```
connect(mapStateToProps, { selectBook })(BookList)
```

You may also want to look at the mdn link below if you are unsure of why `{ selectBook }` and `{ selectBook: selectBook }` are equivalent.

reference:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-todos-and-specific-action-creators-addtodo-and-deletetodo-with-shorthand-syntax

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015